# -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11c824e0

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, web-services

I face this error, Please help me for this and here is my code:

```
if(![[tmparr objectForKey:@"error"] isEqualToString:@"No data found"]){
resultArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil]];}
```

Comment: Show how you declare and set tmparr.

Comment: Can you post your JSON response here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this issue thanks to all

```
if( [tmparr isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] && ![[tmparr objectForKey:@"error"] isEqualToString:@"No data found"]){

                 resultArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil]];
         }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `tmparr` is a variable of type `NSArray`, but i guess you're treating it as an `NSDictionary` in this line:

```
[tmparr objectForKey:@"error"];
```

Comment: No it's NSDictionary.
NSDictionary *tmparr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

Comment: No, it's NSArray. The fact that you declared it as NSDictionary doesn't make object returned by NSJSONSerialization a dictionary. It is an array. It would be an array even if you declared it as a string. Just send it description message and you'll see its internal representation

Comment: I bet it is, check it with `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([tmparr class]));`